# In CakePHP, how to have a Table belongsToMany OtherTable hasMany AnotherTable

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am creating a tool that allows to generate dynamic forms. There are several tables in question:

- Form  [the Form master table]
- FormField [JoinTable to Field]
- Field [the fields available for inclusion in Form]
- FieldValidation [The table containing relation data between the FormField and the Validation option]
- Validation [The available Validation options]

For the FieldValidation - this could in effect be a hasMany from Field, but I am unsure of whether I need to set up this relation from the Field table, or from the join table `FieldValidation`. The `Validation` table literally just includes the definitions for the validation options. This does not actually *need* to be a `belongsToMany` relation from the FormField/Field table. A `hasMany` is fine if that simplifies things.

Is this even possible?

```
Form -> [FormField] -> Field -> [FieldValidation] -> Validation
```

I have never done this before - so if there is a better way to approach this, I am all ears. My main concern is being able to select `Form`, contain `Field's`, and then contain the `Validation` for each field selected. Obviously, multiple validation rules can be selected per field.

Comment: If you are using a join table, don't you need a `hasAndBelongsToMany` connection? (HABTM)

Comment: @Mary the validation table is actually a bunch of predefined fields in a class. It is basically just going to be a hasMany

Comment: But doesn’t `Field` have many `Validation` and `Validation` have many `Field`?

Comment: Are you unsure about your database schema, or do you just don't know how to express the associations on the CakePHP side? From the description it sounds as if the schema allows to associate any `Validation` with any `Form/Field` combination? On the other hand one could think you're talking about restricting the possible `Validation` to `FormField` selections by associating `Field` with `Validation`?

Comment: I am sure of both. I just didnt want to have a belongsToMany come out of the join table. I need a way to contain it and retrieve the data gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but I did resolve this issue.

**ERD Diagram of Physical Relationship in DB**
[image: ERD Relationship Diagram Example]

**Model: UsersTable**

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('username');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsToMany('Projects', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'project_id',
            'through' => 'ProjectsUsers'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('ProjectsUsers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);

    }
}
```

**Model: ProjectsTable**

```
class ProjectsTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('projects');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'through' => 'ProjectsUsers'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('ProjectsUsers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
        ]);

    }
}
```

**Model: ProjectsUsersTable** - *this is the model for the JOIN table (through)*

```
class ProjectsUsersTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('projects_users');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('Projects', [
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('ProjectsUsersPermissions', [
            'foreignKey' => 'projects_users_id'
        ]);

    }
}
```

**Model: ProjectsUsersPermissions** - *this is the relation to the join table*

```
class ProjectsUsersPermissionsTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('projects_users_permissions');
        $this->displayField('role');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('ProjectsUsers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'projects_users_id'
        ]);

    }
}
```

**Then the controller find action**

```
$this->Projects->find()
        ->where(
            [
                'Projects.id' => $projectId
            ]
        )
        ->contain(
            [
                'Users',   // through belongsToMany
                'ProjectsUsers' => [  // through hasMany [joinTableModel]
                    'ProjectsUsersPermissions'  // through hasMany 
                ]
            ]
        )
        ->first();
```

This may be overkill for this scenario, and it is not my exact implementation - so don't think I am just doing unnecessary joins/contains. In my real life scenario, this works perfectly.

Hope this helps someone!